# <ask> acces-reject on freeradius

Tags: freeradius

i just installed freeradius 1.1.7 from tarbal.
Actually i don't get any error in compile and installation process.
first,when i try to running on debug mode everything looked running well

```
stantiated acct_unique (acct_unique) 
Module: Loaded detail 
 detail: detailfile = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{Client-IP-Address}/detail-%Y%m%d"
 detail: detailperm = 384
 detail: dirperm = 493
 detail: locking = no
Module: Instantiated detail (detail) 
Module: Loaded radutmp 
 radutmp: filename = "/usr/local/var/log/radius/radutmp"
 radutmp: username = "%{User-Name}"
 radutmp: case_sensitive = yes
 radutmp: check_with_nas = yes
 radutmp: perm = 384
 radutmp: callerid = yes
Module: Instantiated radutmp (radutmp) 
Listening on authentication *:1812
Listening on accounting *:1813
Ready to process requests.
```

Then i try to test user with following command, but i got reject packet from freeradius

```
radtest user 1111 127.0.0.1 1812 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 19 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
    User-Name = "user"
    User-Password = "1111"
    NAS-IP-Address = 255.255.255.255
    NAS-Port = 1812
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 127.0.0.1:1812, id=19, length=20
```

on debug mode i got message like bellow :

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1:50886, id=90, length=56
    User-Name = "user"
    User-Password = "1111"
    NAS-IP-Address = 255.255.255.255
    NAS-Port = 1812
  Processing the authorize section of radiusd.conf
modcall: entering group authorize for request 0
  modcall[authorize]: module "preprocess" returns ok for request 0
  modcall[authorize]: module "chap" returns noop for request 0
  modcall[authorize]: module "mschap" returns noop for request 0
    rlm_realm: No '@' in User-Name = "user", looking up realm NULL
    rlm_realm: No such realm "NULL"
  modcall[authorize]: module "suffix" returns noop for request 0
  rlm_eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
  modcall[authorize]: module "eap" returns noop for request 0
    users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 153
  modcall[authorize]: module "files" returns ok for request 0
radius_xlat:  'user'
rlm_sql (sql): sql_set_user escaped user --> 'user'
radius_xlat:  'SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, op           FROM radcheck           WHERE Username = 'user'           ORDER BY id'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserving sql socket id: 4
radius_xlat:  'SELECT radgroupcheck.id,radgroupcheck.GroupName,radgroupcheck.Attribute,radgroupcheck.Value,radgroupcheck.op  FROM radgroupcheck,usergroup WHERE usergroup.Username = 'user' AND usergroup.GroupName = radgroupcheck.GroupName ORDER BY radgroupcheck.id'
rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 1146 received
rlm_sql_getvpdata: database query error
radius_xlat:  'SELECT id, UserName, Attribute, Value, op           FROM radreply           WHERE Username = 'user'           ORDER BY id'
radius_xlat:  'SELECT radgroupreply.id,radgroupreply.GroupName,radgroupreply.Attribute,radgroupreply.Value,radgroupreply.op  FROM radgroupreply,usergroup WHERE usergroup.Username = 'user' AND usergroup.GroupName = radgroupreply.GroupName ORDER BY radgroupreply.id'
rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 1146 received
rlm_sql_getvpdata: database query error
rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 4
  modcall[authorize]: module "sql" returns ok for request 0
rlm_pap: Found existing Auth-Type, not changing it.
  modcall[authorize]: module "pap" returns noop for request 0
modcall: leaving group authorize (returns ok) for request 0
  rad_check_password:  Found Auth-Type System
auth: type "System"
  Processing the authenticate section of radiusd.conf
modcall: entering group authenticate for request 0
  modcall[authenticate]: module "unix" returns notfound for request 0
modcall: leaving group authenticate (returns notfound) for request 0
auth: Failed to validate the user.
Delaying request 0 for 1 seconds
Finished request 0
Going to the next request
--- Walking the entire request list ---
Waking up in 1 seconds...
--- Walking the entire request list ---
Waking up in 1 seconds...
--- Walking the entire request list ---
Sending Access-Reject of id 90 to 127.0.0.1 port 50886
Waking up in 4 seconds...
--- Walking the entire request list ---
Cleaning up request 0 ID 90 with timestamp 5130196a
Nothing to do.  Sleeping until we see a request.
```

what should i do to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: if you'd read through the error messages, you'd see "Mysql check-error: 1146" mysql error #1146 - table doesn't exist. you haven't configured mysql properly (or at all).

Answer (score 1):

May be you should check your **clients.conf** file.

I think you didn't mention **127.0.0.1** as **ipaddr** in **client localhost{}**.